# How to rounding number using Math.Round in c#?

Tags: c#

When value is 4.005, it should be rounded to 4.01. But When I use this code, result is only 4.

```
  var result = Math.Round(number*100)/100;
   Console.WriteLine($"{result:0.00}");

  OR

  var result = Math.Round(number,2);
   Console.WriteLine($"{result:0.00}");
```

Expected result is with 2 decimal values. 4.01.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx):

> [...] Rounds a decimal value to a specified number of fractional digits, and rounds midpoint values **to the nearest even number**.

Take a look at the text in bold.

If the value is `4.005` then the midpoint value `.005` will be rounded to `.00`, and not to `.01` because the former is even and the latter is odd.

So, the value you are getting is the expected one.

Instead, you want to use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131275(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = Math.Round(number, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
Console.WriteLine($"{result:0.00}");
```